# How to prevent adding suffix in blank lines of large string? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, prefix

I want to add prefix to each line of large string excluding blank lines. Below code adds prefix to blank lines as well. I have searched many websites but I am unable to find proper solution to do that. here is my code:

```
string txt_input="abc \n \n efg \n \n \n hij";
string source = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, txt_input);

string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, source
                 .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                 .Select(line => txt_prefix + line));
```

Comment: did you try swapping the "/n" with a "\n"?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Why are you using `Join` twice? Do you want to have a new line after each character?

Comment: Considering you have the desired string with new line characters in a string variable called `text`, you could do: `IEnumerable<string> linesWithPrefix = text.Split(Environment.NewLine).Select(line => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) ? line : txt_prefix + line);`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit fuzzy so I'll work on the assumption that your input looks like the txt_input you provided:

`string txt_input="abc \n \n efg \n \n \n hij";`

and you want an output of the sort:

`var ouput = "myPrefix_abc \n \n myPrefix_efg \n \n \n myPrefix_hij";"`

Something like this should work:

```
string prefix = "myPrefix_";
string txt_input="abc \n \n efg \n \n \n hij";
var split = txt_input.Split(new[] {"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
var prefixedList = new List<string>();
foreach(var line in split){
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) {
        prefixedList.Add(line);
        continue;
    }
    prefixedList.Add(prefix + line);
}
var output = string.Join("\n", prefixedList.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

If you actually want to see the `\n` chars replace the second last line with

`var output = string.Join("\\n", prefixedList.ToArray());`

(note the second '\' before the '\n')